# Can different RTL8187-based wifi adapters have different mw power specs?

Tags: wireless-networking

The various RTL8187-based wifi adapters I have are rated 300mw, 500mw, 1000mw, 1500mw, etc, on their product packaging.  Are they all correct or are all of them lying?  What's the *real* (or *normal*) power-rating of a wifi adapter based on the RTL8187 chip?

Comment: From my experience, this is perfectly normal. Although I can't answer the second part of your question, it is entirely feasible that the adapters can have different power specifications.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the chip itself does not determine the power of a WiFi adapter. The chip only produces a signal which is then amplified and broadcast by a transmitter. It is this transmitter which determines the adapter's power.

So what you read is perfectly normal.